# Word pattern matching and substitute using re module

Tags: python, python-re

I have a text list with grammatic problem:

```
List1 = ['He had no hungeror sleepelse he would have told']
```

I want to get the full sentence but corrected, i.e.

```
['He had no hunger or sleep else he would have told']
```

I have created a conjunction list:

```
conj = ['else', 'or']
```

I am able to identify the line that contains the conjunction word `else` but not how to replace the word or remove `else` and then append `else` with a space between the two words `sleep` and `else`.

```
for line in List1:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('[A-Za-z]*else',line):
        print(line)
```

Please guide me how to do this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a place to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: I have indeed gone through documentation. It is not that I have not tried at all and just posting questions. Help or hint about how to proceed is appreciated and that is the purpose of stack overflow as it can be reused by others as well.

Comment: You may know a lot, and I have not yet reached that level. That doesn't mean that I have not made an honest attempt. Little tips help a lot, complete solution has not been expected.

Comment: Hang tight, someone will likely eventually answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways to do this; the right way and the wrong way. Since your question tagged 're', I'll assume you want the wrong way:

```
>>> line = 'He had no hungeror sleepelse he would have told'
>>> conj = ['else', 'or']
>>> pattern = r"(?<=\S)(%s)(?=\s|$)" % ("|".join(conj))
>>> re.sub(pattern, r' \1', line)
'He had no hunger or sleep else he would have told'
```

The right way would be to split the string, loop through each word, and each conj, and if the word ends in the conj, add the two separate words to the original string, and if it doesn't add the word on it's own.

Comment: I have tried this:for line in List1:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('[A-Za-z]*eller',line):
        cop1 = line.split(r'eller')
        cop2 = ' eller'.join(cop1)
        print(cop2)

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting 'eller' from?

Comment: Oh - I see where you're coming from now; if the conj is else, you're trying to split the whole line on the 'else' or 'or'. I don't think that approach is going to work, since you could have words like 'more' or 'Chelsea'.

Comment: Hi @Rory Browne,  thank you a lot for your answer. Interested to know why you think the 1st solution is wrong way. If I have many lines, then spitting into words and joining back would be performance-heavy. I had actually started the 'right' i.e. 2nd solution but thought that for too many lines, it would be time-consuming and regex would be better.

By the way, the pattern is elegant. So, it is checking for a word pattern starting with nonspace character and ending with space. The '%s' looks for the conjunction word in the 1st wordpattern and replace with the .join part. Superb solution!

Comment: Maybe regex is the right answer, but it's something you have to be very careful with to avoid coming up with unreadable code. Compare this for example with what what a non-regex string operations based solution would look like: r'((1?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])'. Can you tell me what it checks for? Can you tell me that everyone on your team who might have to maintain your code in the future will understand it? I try to approach a problem as though regex is the wrong answer, until I've demonstrated that the alternative is much less readable, performant or idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code that simply searches for a conjunction "else" or "or" preceeded by a letter without blank space and adds the blank space (in-place). It uses the `re.sub` substitution method. It also uses f-string for better readability. Not sure it performs the full job, but it may bring you some clues to improve your program:

```
import re

List1 = ['He had no hungeror sleepelse he would have told']
conj = ['else', 'or']

for i in range(len(List1)):
    for c in conj:
        List1[i] = re.sub(f"(\w){c}", fr"\1 {c}", List1[i])
        
print(List1) # ['He had no hunger or sleep else he would have told']
```

Comment: There's a problem here if your word contains one of the conj words that's not at the ends of the word. Try the following example (I'm not sure if 'proctored' is actually a word, but it will suffice for this example): List1 = ["Mike proctored the wedding in Chelsea"]

Comment: @RoryBrowne My answer just tries to... answer the question. I agree with the fact it does not manage all cases, but it guides the requester to find himself his expected solution.